# thymeleaf: attribute based on AbstractTextChildModifierAttrProcessor not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, processor, dialect

In my current spring-boot application, I am trying implement this attribute `setting:attr` to some of my tags:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" th:href="@{/}" setting:attr="Project name"></a>
```

the dialect and processor classes which handle this attribute are:

- dialect:

```
public class SettingDialect extends AbstractDialect {

  public SettingDialect() {
    super();
  }

  //
  // All of this dialect's attributes and/or tags
  // will start with 'menu:'
  //
  public String getPrefix() {
    return "setting";
  }


  //
  // The processors.
  //
  @Override
  public Set<IProcessor> getProcessors() {
    final Set<IProcessor> processor = new HashSet<IProcessor>();
    processor.add(new PreferenceProcessor());
    return processor;
  }

}
```

- processor:

```
    public class PreferenceProcessor extends AbstractTextChildModifierAttrProcessor {

      public PreferenceProcessor() {
        super("attr");
      }

      public int getPrecedence() {
        return 1000;
      }

      @Override
      public String getText(final Arguments arguments, final Element element, final String attributeName) {
        return "Hello, "  + element.getAttributeValue(attributeName) + "!";
      }

    }
```

but when I run the application and access a page with a tag using this attribute, it isn't processed (the source code display `setting:attr="Project name"` instead of the appropriate value).

Anyone can give me a hint of what's wrong here?

**UPDATE**

the configuration for thymeleaf is this:

```js
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafContext {

  @Bean
  public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine  =  new SpringTemplateEngine();

    final Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<IDialect>();
    dialects.add( new SpringSecurityDialect() );
    dialects.add ( new FormDialect() );
    dialects.add ( new ListaDialect() );
    dialects.add ( new MenuDialect() );
    dialects.add ( new SettingDialect() );
    engine.setDialects( dialects );

    return engine;
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you register the dialect class with Spring?

Comment: can we see the rest of the configuration then?

Comment: @rhinds added to the post.

Comment: Are you getting any logging? Seems strange, if the attribute remains unchanged in the end output, would suggest that the processor is not being invoked at all.